# Is it possible to use .htaccsess to remove .jpg form a url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it possible to use .htaccsess to remove .jpg form a url. For example, if I have www.test.com/9q8gnhq, a valid link, but I want users to go to www.test.com/9q8gnhq.jpg,not a vlid link, but I need it to auto convert back to the url without the .jpg at the end.

```
# BEGIN YOURLS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /somedir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /yourls-loader.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END YOURLS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.jpg [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.jpg$ $1? [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}\.jpg -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.jpg [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /yourls-loader.php [L]
```

Comment: Note to downvoter: Answers should please be downvoted on its merit not on the quality of the question.

Comment: I updated my post with the current rewrite I am using, could you help me from that?

Comment: ok try updated code now.

Comment: It redirects me to my main index(html) page for some reason instead of the url shortner pgp page

Comment: see updated code and let me know which URL did you enter in browser?

Comment: Updated it. This is what works- http://rizimg.com/omsdu This is what does not work- http://rizimg.com/omsdu.jpg

Comment: Why did you have `RewriteBase` in your rule when your URL doesn't have `somedir`?

Comment: Just never took it out. Either way with or without, it does the same thing.

Comment: I had a typo and removed faulty `RewriteBase` line. Use my latest updated code.